# Python: Subclasses with the same set of __init__ arguments as base class, plus additional arguments, without using super()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how to explain my question, so I will do the best I can.

I have base class `Price`:

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, contractid, *args, **kwargs):
        self.contractid = contractid
```

I have a bunch of classes that derive from `Price`. Each subclass requires the arguments `Price` does, plus some additional arguments. For example...

```
class BestAvailablePrice(Price):
    def __init__(self, contractid, sell_type)
        super().__init__(contractid)
        self.sell_type = sell_type

class MaxInvestedPrice(Price):
    def __init__(self, contractid, n_shares, cumulative=True)
        super().__init__(contractid)
        self.n_shares = n_shares
        self.cumulative = cumulative

....
```

The problem with using `super().__init__(contractid)` is that if `Price.__init__()` changes, I need to update all of my subclasses as well. For example, if I decide Price also needs a `marketid` argument:

```
class Price:

    # new __init__ method includes marketid argument
    def __init__(self, contractid, marketid, *args, **kwargs):  
        self.contractid = contractid
        self.marketid = marketid
```

Then I am stuck going back and updating all of the subclasses as well.

Something I've been doing has been to declare a `setup_init_args(*args, **kwargs)` method, and defining the additional parameters in there:

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, contractid, *args, **kwargs):
        self.contractid = contractid
        self.setup_init_args(*args, **kwargs)

    def setup_init_args(*args, **kwargs)
        pass # overridden in subclasses

class BestAvailablePrice:
    def setup_init_args(sell_type)
        self.sell_type = sell_type
```

This gets my base object's attributes set correctly, and I can use a factory method to instantiate my objects:

```
marketid = 1000
contractid = 2020

def get_price_object(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    return obj(marketid, contractid, *args, **kwargs)

bap = get_price_object(BestAvailablePrice, sell_type = 'sell')
```

If I change the base class's init method, I only need to change it in the factory method. This works and I will get the correct object, but...

### Downsides:

#### 1. My IDE doesn't know what type of object I'm getting.

I could do:

```
def get_price_object(obj, *args, **kwargs) -> Price:
```

but then it thinks I'm only getting a Price object. I've tried using TypeVar from python's typing library, but I couldn't seem to get this to work. Setting something with `# type: BestAvailablePrice` is a workaround but not ideal.

#### 2. My IDE doesn't display expected arguments in the code-completion for `BestAvailablePrice`

When I type `bap = get_price_object(BestAvailablePrice, )` I would love to see the additional arguments needed for a BestAvailablePrice object. Is there any way to get that to show up? I have dozens of price types, and it becomes difficult to remember which class requires which arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subclasses don't have to duplicate the named parameters from `Price`, if you agree to always use keyword arguments when calling. Remember, any keyword argument it doesn't recognize is added to `kwargs` to be passed along. You can *insist* upon keyword arguments being used by making all of `__init__`'s parameters keyword-only.

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, *, contractid, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.contractid = contractid


class BestAvailablePrice(Price):
    def __init__(self, *, sell_type, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sell_type = sell_type


class MaxInvestedPrice(Price):
    def __init__(self, *, n_shares, cumulative=True, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_shares = n_shares
        self.cumulative = cumulative
```

Note that `Price.__init__` should *also* use `super`, to handle multiple inheritance where `Price` is not necessarily the last class before `object` in the MRO. If you do things properly, `**kwargs` will be empty when `object.__init__` is called.

---

Regarding your factory method, you can add an appropriate type hint:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

P = TypeVar('P', bound=Price)

def get_price_object(obj: Type[P] , *args, **kwargs) -> P:
```

though that may not help your IDE suggest expected parameter names.

Comment: If you put a lone `*` in the signature before the first parameter, you can enforce that all constructor arguments are given as keywords: `def __init__(self, *, sell_type, **kwargs):`.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that.